# Populating a View from a data array of objects Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a data store in a variable **requestData** which I want to use in populating the notification component view

```
requestData = {
    "bookId": "5e5bb8ac59441513cca2e64c",
    "bookTitle": "Take Great Photographs",
    "request": [
        {
            "_id": "5e21d286b3ee501ebc39d899",
            "firstname": "Ibaji",
            "lastname": "Offor"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e2c5a20aff8434278639ff5",
            "firstname": "Cheksmate",
            "lastname": "Fidelis"
        }
    ]
}
```

the view is supposed to look like the image below after the view has been populated with the above data

[image]

this is the code for the notification.component.html

```
<section class="main profile " my-books>
    <div class="profile-header">
      <h1>Notifications</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="book-list-header">
      <h2>Showing Recent Notifications</h2>
      <!-- <span>(Confirm by click the recieved button once book is returned)</span> -->
    </div>

    <div history *ngFor="let item of requestData">
      <a [routerLink]="['details']">
        <h3>9:15 AM | Mon, Feb 11, 2019</h3>
        <div class="first">
          <span>
            <span class="image-cropper" style=" width: 36px; height: 36px;">
              <img src="assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="profile image" avatar>
            </span>
            <h4>{{item.request.firstname}} {{item.request.lastname}}</h4>
          </span>

          <span>
            <h3>Book Title</h3>
            <h4>{{item.bookTitle}}</h4>
          </span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

</section>
```

Any attempt to help will be really appreciated

Comment: What is your current result with your try?? Explain what you have tried and what issue you are facing right now..

Comment: The above code is what I have tried, the issue is trying to make the view into two because of the request array in the requestData above

Comment: I have posted the answer below, feel free to accept if it solves your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above mentioned `requestData`, the data is an object, and you are trying to use `*ngFor="let item of requestData"` on object which is invalid and it should throw the error.

Reason is array's are only the iterables in `*ngFor`.. So change your above code with the following,

```
<div history *ngFor="let item of requestData.request">
  <a [routerLink]="['details']">
    <h3>9:15 AM | Mon, Feb 11, 2019</h3>
    <div class="first">
      <span>
        <span class="image-cropper" style=" width: 36px; height: 36px;">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" style="width:50px; border: 2px solid #fff; border-radius:50%" alt="profile image" avatar>
        </span>
        <h4>{{item.firstname}} {{item.lastname}}</h4>
      </span>

      <span>
        <h3>Book Title</h3>
        <h4>{{requestData.bookTitle}}</h4>
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here `requestData.request` is an array so you need to iterate only this array using `*ngFor` and replace, `{{item.request.firstname}}` with `{{item.firstname}}` and so on for all related data.

To assign the value of `bookTitle`, you need to use like this directly from the object,

```
{{requestData.bookTitle}}
```

> [**Working stackblitz example here..**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vf2nmy)